# Locking if condition

Tags: c#, locking, if-statement, nested, deadlock

I have a problem where I need to call a thread-safe method (i.e. one that uses locking internally) if a condition is true. The condition I am checking reads a variable shared among many threads (_count), so I need to lock when I read it to avoid fuzzy reads. Wouldn't this cause a nested monitor lockout (deadlock), since I am locking an already thread-safe method call?

Example below:

```
lock (this)
{
    if (_count <= 10)
    {
        _someObj.DoSomethingThreadSafe(); //this method has its only locking internally
    }
}
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: This piece of code isn't sufficient to illustrate the problem.  Why is it bad that `DoSomethingThreadSafe` is locking something?

Comment: He's asking if his outer lock won't deadlock with an inner lock on the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, monitors can be acquired recursively in .NET. ([Arguably this was a design mistake](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/09/12/ConditionVariablesAndLockRecursion.aspx), but that's another matter. Likewise I wouldn't generally recommend locking on `this`. I would suggest using a private reference which only the class performing the locking knows about, e.g. a `private readonly object` field, unless you *really* need to expose the lock to other code.)